# FuelPHP mysql_timestamp in models not really DRY

Tags: fuelphp

When creating a model with Oil I realized that that method is always inserted:

```php
protected static $_observers = array(
    'Orm\Observer_CreatedAt' => array(
        'events' => array('before_insert'),
        'mysql_timestamp' => false,
    ),
    'Orm\Observer_UpdatedAt' => array(
        'events' => array('before_update'),
        'mysql_timestamp' => false,
    ),
);
```

Also (with Model_Soft):

```php
protected static $_soft_delete = array(
    'mysql_timestamp' => false,
);
```

But, at the same time, the default value in the Observer classes is `false`:

```php
class Observer_UpdatedAt extends Observer
{
    /**
     * @var  bool  set true to use mySQL timestamp instead of UNIX timestamp
     */
    public static $mysql_timestamp = false;
```

Is there any need to specify a value that is already the default one?

Bonus: Is there any reason to use `datetime` instead of `timestamp` by default? (Apart from the remote possibility that my application will be still online after 2038)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oil puts the default values in for parameters that are most commonly changed after generation. You can omit default values.

Regarding the `datetime`/`timestamp` question, in MySQL `timestamp` is possible to be configured to have a default value of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, and to be updated to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` upon updating. If you need this functionality, `datetime` is not sufficient. However `datetime` can have the value of `0000-00-00 00:00:00`, which is not possible to represent with a timestamp (if you don't consider `null` the same). While `created_at`, and `updated_at` is designed for a specific purpose, you can always think of using it in a way that is aided by this FuelPHP mechanism, but is a slightly different purpose. In these cases you might need `datetime` (to represent dates that are not possible with a timestamp).

I hope this helps.